# What happens when two magnetization fronts hit each other

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Lets say we have 4 rods of iron. Each of these rods has 2 propagating zones of magnetization. The direction and intensity of these fields can be seen in the gif below. The intensity of the magnetization is less than saturation. In each rod, the propagating zones of magnetization are heading towards each other. I'm wondering what will happen when their fronts of magnetization hit each other. I'm wondering what the intensity and direction the magnetization of the yellow and green zones will be for all four rods.

[image]

For the first rod I'm wondering if the two propagating zones of magnetization will either annihilate each other, pass through each other unchanged, or do something else. I'm also wondering what the field is in the center when they are overlapping each other(like if it's both fields added together, averaged, or something else). I'm fairly certain the green part will have no magnetization.

For the second rod I'm wondering if the two propagating zones of magnetization will either annihilate each other, pass through each other unchanged, or do something else. I'm fairly certain the zone in the center when they are overlapping each other is unmagnetized due to the symmetry regarding the equal intensities and opposing magnetic fields.

For the third and forth rods I'm wondering if the two propagating zones of magnetization will either partially annihilate each other, pass through each other unchanged, or do something else. I'm also wondering what the field is in the center when they are overlapping each other.

I haven't been able to find anything on the internet regarding the interaction of two magnetization fronts with each other. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Flux lines won't cross (cf [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/81603/25301)), so I think you need to rethink your model.

Comment: That doesn't matter. The fields of the propagating zones of magnetization are the same as those of a moving bar magnet. You also don't need to look at it in terms of field lines. You could just take the superposition of the two fields instead.

Comment: Ferromagnets like iron are fully magnetized at the microscopic level, but may have such disorder that the large-sample net magnetization is nil.   The 'propogating wave' of  magnetizations is not a recognizable physical event.

Comment: It has to be a physical event. If you have a ferromagnetic core(lets say it's shaped like a torus like in a toroidal transformer) and you put a current through a loop around part of it, then it'll create a magnetic field. This magnetic field will then propagate through the ferromagnetic core by magnetizing it. Since magnetization isn't instantaneous, there must be something akin to a wave of magnetization. I know that the way magnetization occurs is by magnetic dipoles in the medium rotating slightly in the direction of the magnetic field. I'm asking about large-scale magnetization.

Answer (score 1):

You should think about why the "wave" propagates. Let's think about a dipole near the wavefront. The part the wave has traced over will have all dipoles mostly aligned (`>>>>`), while the unreached part has the dipoles pointing in random direction (`<>v^`), including the one we are looking at:

```
>>>> ^<><
>>>> v^<v
>>>> <>v<
>>>> ^<>^
```

so a dipole would sense no force from the (right) untraced region since they mostly cancel for each dipole, while from the (left) traced region it will sense a force to align itself with the other dipoles. So the wavefront will propagate to the right.

Now imagine what happens when two wavefronts come from both sides. In the case of a torus they would be wavefronts with the same direction of magnetization:

```
>>>> ^ >>>>
>>>> v >>>>
>>>> < >>>>
>>>> ^ >>>>
(->)   (<-)
```

so the unordered dipoles in the center will just align themselves with both magnetized regions:

```
>>>> > >>>>
>>>> > >>>>
>>>> > >>>>
>>>> > >>>>
```

as soon as this happens no change will happen, the wavefronts have in a sense annihilated.

In practice I think the dipoles will oscillate rather than immediately snap to the correct position, so we might have a "disturbance wave" which passes through each other rather than annihilating.

Another interesting case is when the wavefronts have opposing magnetization:

```
>>>> ^ <<<<
>>>> v <<<<
>>>> < <<<<
>>>> ^ <<<<
(->)   (<-)
```

in this case the dipoles in the center can align themselves with either the left or the right wall, but since this will be purely random (both are equivalent in terms of energy), this will just cause a fluctuation of the "domain wall" to the left or right. Propagation has stopped and we have a static domain wall.